# Generate random points inside a parallelogram

Tags: java, android, algorithm, location

I need to write some code but I don't really know where to start. 
First my input is 4 geographic points ( lat, lon ) ( double ). 
This 4 points create a parallelogram. I need a way to:

1. Go over the "matrix" formed by the parallelgram in some way.
2. If point 1 is not posible find random points inside the parallelogram.

Thanks in advance!

edit:

My actual code is able to iterate inside a rectangle, here it goes

```
while (!finished){
    if (actualLong> longitudMax){
        if(actualLat>latitudMax){
            //finish
            {... return;}
         actualLong = longitudMin;
         actuallat += adddistance;
     else{
         actualLong += addDistance;
     }



LongitudMin = minimum lon.
LongitudMax = maximum lon.
LatitudMin = minimum lat.
LatitudMax = maximum lat.
```

Comment: Have a go yourself first! Show that you have put some effort in and then show us your code here so that we can help you adjust it as necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to interpolate points inside.
Let's say you have i,j coordinates inside (0 <= i,j <= 1). Now you can generate a line. Say your paralelolgram is ABCD. Then you get `L1 = A*i + B*(1-i)` and `L2 = D*i + C*(1-i)` (note that I swapped C and D because you should go in the same direction). Then a point inside will be `X = L1 * j + L2*(1-j)`.

So if you make for loops that go in some steps from 0 to 1 for your i and j you should get a nice grid inside your parallelogram. If you want random points just generate random values of i and j.

Notes:

- You can go outside `[0,1]` but that will give you points outside the parallelogram.
- For 0 and 1 you will get points on the edges of the parallelogram, skip or include as you want.
- This works for any 4 points but the grid will be skewed to reflect the shape you have.
- Since you work with angles be careful when you cross 0 (you go from 2pi to 0). You can fix it by making adding 2pi or 360 so that the numbers still make sense.
- This will follow the curvature of the space, so if you parallelogram is close to one of the poles you will get strange results because the space is so warped. In this case you can convert your points to 3d points on a unit sphere, apply the same algorithm and the reproject your result point into lat,long space.

Comment: Thanks mate! i'll work from here :P